# buscar minimo y maximo usando @queryparam

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

¿alguien ha trabajado con apis ?, como puedo hacer consulta con @QueryParam

quiero hacer una consulta general, y de alli quiero que se muestre la consulta por id de la 1 a la 5, es decir , mostrar el minimo y maximo de la consulta

este es mi api
https://localhost:8443/ApiControlleer/pagos?minimo=1&maximo=5

este es mi metoso

```
  @GET
        @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        public String getTipoBusqueda(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo,
                                      @ApiParam(value = "minimo") @QueryParam("minimo") final int minimo,
                                      @ApiParam(value = "maximo") @QueryParam("maximo") final int maximo) {
    
            final Collection<ControlPagoData> pagoMasivo = this.readPlataformService.getPagomasivo();
```

Comment: Cuál es el error/problema?

Comment: perdon no le habia pasado parametros a mi servicio maximo y minimo